# WPF DataGridComboBoxColumn Binding: 'DeferRefresh' is not allowed during an AddNew or EditItem transaction'?

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework, xaml

Got a `DataGridComboBoxColumn` in a WPF grid but having some binding issues. I can successfully bind to an `ObservableCollection<String>` property but when I try to bind to a column in an `ObservableCollection<T>` of a EF entity table, I get an exception despite the bound column being a varchar:

```
'DeferRefresh' is not allowed during an AddNew or EditItem transaction'
```

Here is my Xaml:

```
<DataGrid Margin="5" AutoGenerateColumns="False" ItemsSource="{Binding MembershipsCollection}">
   <DataGrid.Columns>
      <DataGridComboBoxColumn Header="Region" Width="SizeToHeader" DisplayMemberPath="{Binding RegionShortCodeCollection}">
        <DataGridComboBoxColumn.ElementStyle>
             <Style>
                 <Setter Property="ComboBox.ItemsSource" Value="{Binding DataContext.RegionShortCodeCollection, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type vm:AccountsViewModel}}}" />
              </Style>
             </DataGridComboBoxColumn.ElementStyle>
          <DataGridComboBoxColumn.EditingElementStyle>
               <Style>
                  <Setter Property="ComboBox.ItemsSource" Value="{Binding DataContext.RegionShortCodeCollection, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type v:AccountsView}}}" />
                </Style>
             </DataGridComboBoxColumn.EditingElementStyle>
           </DataGridComboBoxColumn>
         <DataGridTextColumn Header="ProductCode" Binding="{Binding Path=ProductCode}" Width="SizeToHeader"/>                                                                  
        </DataGrid.Columns>
       </DataGrid>
```

& my `ObservableCollection<T>` in the ViewModel. This is populated by a method invoked from the constructor:

```
private ObservableCollection<String> _RegionShortCodeCollection;
public ObservableCollection<String> RegionShortCodeCollection
{
    get { return _RegionShortCodeCollection; }
    set
    {
        _RegionShortCodeCollection = value;
        OnPropertyChanged("RegionShortCodeCollection");
    }
}
```

Any ideas as to why this is occurring with one collection but not the other?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this. There was an 'INSERT' trigger on the underlying DB table that was preventing the insert from the application. I changed the trigger to an 'AFTER INSERT' which allow Entity Framework to persist the change before the trigger was invoked.